# How to completely remove notepad++ installed via wine?

Tags: wine, uninstall, 21.10

I am running `wine6` on Ubuntu 21.10

I installed notepad++ using the command -

```
wine <package-name>.exe
```

now I uninstalled it using the command -

```
wine uninstaller
```

Then I followed the windows dialog to uninstall it

Now in `/home/payel/.wine/drive_c/Program Files` I deleted `Notepad++`

Also in `/home/payel/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files` directory there is no longer any Notepad++

The following is the content of my `/home/payel/.local/share/applications` directory -

```
mimeinfo.cache              wine-extension-gif.desktop  wine-extension-ini.desktop   wine-extension-msp.desktop  wine-extension-rtf.desktop  wine-extension-vbs.desktop
wine                        wine-extension-hlp.desktop  wine-extension-jfif.desktop  wine-extension-pdf.desktop  wine-extension-txt.desktop  wine-extension-wri.desktop
wine-extension-chm.desktop  wine-extension-htm.desktop  wine-extension-jpe.desktop   wine-extension-png.desktop  wine-extension-url.desktop  wine-extension-xml.desktop
```

Here I can't understand which one is Notepad++, if any.

And, the following is the content of my `/usr/share/applications` directory -

```
apport-gtk.desktop                gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop      gnome-thunderbolt-panel.desktop       org.freedesktop.IBus.Panel.Emojier.desktop         org.gnome.Software.desktop
apturl.desktop                    gnome-display-panel.desktop          gnome-ubuntu-panel.desktop            org.freedesktop.IBus.Panel.Extension.Gtk3.desktop  org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
bluetooth-sendto.desktop          gnome-info-overview-panel.desktop    gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop  org.freedesktop.IBus.Setup.desktop                 org.gnome.tweaks.desktop
caffeine.desktop                  gnome-initial-setup.desktop          gnome-usage-panel.desktop             org.gnome.Calculator.desktop                       org.keepassxc.KeePassXC.desktop
caffeine-indicator.desktop        gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop         gnome-user-accounts-panel.desktop     org.gnome.Characters.desktop                       python3.9.desktop
defaults.list                     gnome-language-selector.desktop      gnome-wacom-panel.desktop             org.gnome.ChromeGnomeShell.desktop                 qemu.desktop
display-im6.q16.desktop           gnome-location-panel.desktop         gnome-wifi-panel.desktop              org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop                          rygel.desktop
evolution-calendar.desktop        gnome-lock-panel.desktop             gparted.desktop                       org.gnome.DiskUtility.desktop                      snap-handle-link.desktop
gcr-prompter.desktop              gnome-microphone-panel.desktop       hplj1020.desktop                      org.gnome.eog.desktop                              software-properties-drivers.desktop
gcr-viewer.desktop                gnome-mouse-panel.desktop            htop.desktop                          org.gnome.Evince.desktop                           software-properties-gtk.desktop
gdebi.desktop                     gnome-network-panel.desktop          ibus-setup-m17n.desktop               org.gnome.Evince-previewer.desktop                 software-properties-livepatch.desktop
geoclue-demo-agent.desktop        gnome-notifications-panel.desktop    ibus-setup-table.desktop              org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop           system-config-printer.desktop
gkbd-keyboard-display.desktop     gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop  im-config.desktop                     org.gnome.Extensions.desktop                       timeshift-gtk.desktop
gnome-applications-panel.desktop  gnome-power-panel.desktop            info.desktop                          org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop                       torbrowser.desktop
gnome-background-panel.desktop    gnome-printers-panel.desktop         io.snapcraft.SessionAgent.desktop     org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop                      torbrowser-settings.desktop
gnome-bluetooth-panel.desktop     gnome-region-panel.desktop           laptop-mode-tools.desktop             org.gnome.gedit.desktop                            transmission-gtk.desktop
gnome-camera-panel.desktop        gnome-removable-media-panel.desktop  mimeinfo.cache                        org.gnome.Logs.desktop                             update-manager.desktop
gnome-color-panel.desktop         gnome-search-panel.desktop           mpv.desktop                           org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop                         vim.desktop
gnome-connectivity-panel.desktop  gnome-session-properties.desktop     nautilus-autorun-software.desktop     org.gnome.PowerStats.desktop                       virtualbox.desktop
gnome-control-center.desktop      gnome-sharing-panel.desktop          nm-applet.desktop                     org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop                       wine.desktop
gnome-datetime-panel.desktop      gnome-software-local-file.desktop    nm-connection-editor.desktop          org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop             xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.desktop
gnome-default-apps-panel.desktop  gnome-sound-panel.desktop            nvidia-settings.desktop               org.gnome.Shell.desktop                            yelp.desktop
gnome-diagnostics-panel.desktop   gnome-system-monitor.desktop         openjdk-11-java.desktop               org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.desktop
gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop  gnome-system-monitor-kde.desktop     org.flameshot.Flameshot.desktop       org.gnome.Shell.PortalHelper.desktop
```

Here too I can't find any Notepad++

The problem I am facing is that in Ubuntu applications search I still have the icon for Notepad++ and on clicking on it I get an windows error dialog.

So how can I remove this Notepad++ icon from Ubuntu Applications search?

Here I don't want to remove wine itself, I want to remove only the Notepad++ app.

Answer (score 0):

Application shortcuts are typically located in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` as `.desktop` files.

If you just want to remove the shortcut, simply delete the associated `.desktop` file.

BTW, you don't need wine for a text editor!  There are **so many** great text editors that run natively on Ubuntu: gedit, sublime, emacs, vim, nano, atom... The list goes on and on. I encourage you to find native software because it will save you a lot of time and headache.

Comment: Thank for you answer, I have now provided the content of my `/usr/share/applications` directory. Here I can't find any Notepad++. Also earlier I had provided the content of my `/home/payel/.local/share/applications` Here I can't identify any Notepad++ if present . 

Also I don't intend to use Notepad++. I am only experimenting with `wine`